# How to set a multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I run into a problem wherein I want to divide my items in by array likes this

```
[ 
 1 [ 1[[1][2]]  2[[3][4][5]] ],  2[ 1[[1][2]]  2[[3][4][5]]],  
 3 [ 1[[1][2]] 2[[3][4][5]]],  4[ 1[[1][2]]  2[[3][4][5]]]  
]
```

So basically in the first 1,2,3,4 array are the object array of the arrays... It can basically express like this

- Array parrent [ 1 2 3 4 ]

  - Second array parent [ 1 2 ]

    - First third array [ 1 2 ]
    - Second third array [ 3 4 5 ]

In my code it is something like this

```
    for (let i = 1;i < 4 ;i++) {
        const list = []
        for (let j = 1; j < 16*i ; j++) {
            var list2 = []
            if (j % 5 == 0) {
                const list3 = []
                const list4 = []
                for (let k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    if (k <= 1) {
                        list3.push(`/kgfpics/kgf${k}.png`)
                    } else if ( k >= 4) {
                        list4.push(`/kgfpics/kgf${k}.png`)
                    }
                    list2.push(list3,list4)
                }
                list.push(list2)
            }
        }
        // 1 [ 1 [ [1],[2] ] , 2 [ [3],[4],[5] ] ]
        topiclist.push(list)  
    }
    console.log(topiclist)
```

but the expectation result that I want to happen is not working...Can you notice where I am wrong here? Cause I wanna done my problem for this my project. Thank you very much.

Comment: So is it basically the numbers in your example arrays are the `k` values you are pushing image paths for?

Comment: Yes in third arrays..because I am really confuse of its arranging the array with simultaneous const array brackets.

Comment: why not use a Map()?

Comment: How..I'm not super known in map so I use for loop hehe...

Comment: I'd recommend to also checkout Graph Data structure.. maps are basically named arrays that also allows you to use map.get(key) similar to an object, it's more control in the long run. specially if you're working with typed arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood your desired result. You could hardcode the keys/indices you want to map until the most inner loop where they are finally mapped to the path values.

```js
let k = 1;
const res = Array.from({ length: 4 }).map(() =>
  Array.from({ length: 2 }).map(() =>
    [2, 3].map((length) =>
      Array.from({ length }).map(() => `/kgfpics/kgf${k++}.png`)
    )
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I am sorry sir.. I mean like I want to be that kind of arrangement I want but how do I get all the values from 1 - 45 numbers cause I have 45 images so and arrange them like how you do.. Its not like [1,2,3,4] It is just their separation same as the [1,2] and [3,4,5] .

Comment: the appending array should be like in from 1 - 45 so that I can get all my 45 pictures. but with that kind of arrangement in array.

Comment: @MYTH Ah, I see, ok, let me test another version.

Comment: Oh i already get it sir thanks. I just have to put a  `Array.from({length: 3})` in your codes.. Thank you.

Comment: last question sir can i use this in my advance animation? like anime.js or tweenmax,js or timelinemax.js or other javascript animation stuffs?

Comment: @MYTH Probably, it's all Javascript, so it seems likely. I'm not familiar with any of those you mentioned so I can't say with any certainty.